# 301 Redirect without hosting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

I have a client who is merging two sites into one. For the time being we are just installing a WP plugin to the site to manage the handful of 301 redirects they'd like handled, rather than writing to .htaccess manually.

But in a month or two they'd like to remove the site completely. Is there a way we can redirect traffic to the new combined site once they get rid of their hosting and we no longer have access to their .htaccess?

I have seen some brief mentions of setting the DNS to something but I don't totally understand and I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do. I have not asked the client if they are holding onto the domain name. In order to point the DNS to the new site, we'd need them to still own the old domain, correct? What would I assign the values to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to own the domain to do anything with it including updating DNS name. It wouldn't be smart to let it go.
2. If they don't have hosting on it anymore, then they will need to do [domain forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) with DNS. It can be done with 301 or 302 status codes. This link will show you how to do it on Godaddy. If you don't have Godaddy as your registrar, just look for the instructions for your domain registar.

https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422